# Git, no cache no store password in specific reposiory

Tags: git

In a specific repository, I want to prevent the credentials (i.e. git password) to be stored and cached. Instead, I want the password to be asked everytime someone tries to access the remoter repo.

```
git config credentials.helper = ?
```

I don't want this settings to be applied globally

Comment: To add configuration to a repository, use `git config --local`.

Comment: yes, but what do I do to make git not store the password

Comment: Does this help? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache#_controlling_the_daemon

Comment: No, this is about caching. I want no caching.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+disable+credentials+helper

Comment: `git config --global --unset credential.helper`

Comment: I don't want this settings to be applied globally

Comment: Do you understand `--unset` part?

Comment: I understand the command in so far that it unsets the global credential.helper variable. But I want the global credential.helper to be not affected.